# Perform function when WindowCloseOnTouchOutside

Tags: java, android, xml

I've searched around for a while but I can't seem to find an answer to this. I have a theme for my Android application that closes an activity when the outside is clicked by using the **XML** script `<item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>`

However, I need a function to fire when this is done as it returns to the previous activity and passes information. `onBackPressed()` doesn't seem to pick this up and I can't find any information on what would.

**RESULT**

As far as I can uncover it's not possible to add information to the activity returned to `OnActivityResult` if you are using `windowCloseOnTouchOutside` as it directly uses `onPause()` with no break between.

My solution was to remake the popup window with a transparent surround that would be detected when the player clicks onto it. Then I created a function that is detected when the back button is pressed or the player clicks outside of the window

Comment: If your activity is closing at this stage, Please check the same with `onPause()` and `onDestroy()` as well.

Comment: Thank you, `onPause()` was the answer, I knew it would be something obvious. However, it has raised another issue. I am still unable to pass an intent back through data back through to `onActivityResult()` on the previous screen

Comment: On further examination it appears impossible to `setActivity()` once you reach `onPause()` so I need to find a way of detecting when someone touches outside of the window before then